# asp.net searching for a string

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I have some data coming in from a webpage and I need to filter it based on what comes back.
I have a pre-defined amount of keywords that I want to search for, around 30.

What is the most efficient way to match them up? Because I can have ~2000 records coming in I don't think searching through a list/array/switch-case for every record is too efficient right?

Comment: For performance problems there's only one thing to do: Always measure before assuming anything. What have you tried so far? Did a simple implementation prove to be too inefficient when you tested it?

Comment: Can you specify _"I have some data coming in from a webpage"_? What kind of _records_ do you have?

Comment: If you won't search in every record, how will you get a complete result? the efficiency question has nothing to do with whether you should check all records or not (obviously, you have to check them all), it's *how* you're going to do it...

Comment: If you really worry about the performance, divide the page content into separate section and run the search process parallel !!!

Comment: The records come in as strings and I have just tried the checking through a list (with only 10 records) and I don't see any performance drop so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides list/array/switch-case, the only thing I can think of is Linq.

```
List<string> found = (from str in listOfStringsToSearch 
                     where listOfKeywords.Any(keyword => str.Contains(keyword)) 
                     select str).ToList<string>();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know which serach terms have matching strings, you can use [`Enumerable.Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx):

```
var both = records.Intersect(searchTerms);
```

It is deferred executed, hence does not create a new collection and is not executed until you use it in some way(f.e. `ToList` or `foreach` or `string.Join`).

It internally uses a `Set`, hence it is very efficient.

Here are more informations on set operations in LINQ:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546153.aspx